# How to run bashscript?

Tags: bash, ubuntu, hunspell

I have downloaded the source code from here : https://github.com/hunspell/hunspell

Extracted it into a folder in ubuntu

Then compiled by following the instructions

```
autoreconf -vfi
./configure
make
make install    #if neccesary prefix with sudo
ldconfig        #not needed on windows, on linux sudo may be needed
```

Then i have copy pasted my respected tr.dic and tr.aff files into the src/tools folder

Navigated there in terminal

And then i call the `wordspell` command but it always fails

Here the screenshot

[image]

And this is the wordforms bash script : https://github.com/hunspell/hunspell/blob/a6d32ee604e99ffc1919f38664817a2ee1500774/src/tools/wordforms

Comment: `./wordforms` instead of `wormform` if you haven't added it to your `$PATH`

Answer (score 1):

1. it's `./wordforms` or `./wordforms.sh`
2. You may need to make it executable with `chmod +x wordforms`

Answer (score 0):

You can see there is a file with the name *wordforms.sh*.
you can make it executable as

```
chmod +x  wordforms.sh
```

then execute it as

```
./wordforms.sh [arguments]
```

or else,

```
bash wordforms.sh [arguments]
```